# How to count occurrence of different features on a category in Qliksense and output a bar graph?

Tags: data-visualization, qlikview, qliksense, alteryx, qlik-expression

I am quite new to Qlik and I am trying to make a measure that counts different categories for outputing a bar graph with the count of each category on said graph. Anyone know how to do this?
[image: Dataframe]

Right now I am processing the raw data on Alteryx to output this, not sure if there is a way to couple the two programs.

I tried something like: Count({<Category={'Feature'}>}Category), but it does not really work. I will post a sample to help clarify how my df looks like and the graph that I need to output.

[image: Bar Graph output nested by category]

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to count as there does not appear to be a `Category` field in your data.

Comment: Each field is a `Category` , and each unique value on this `Category` is a `Feature`.

Comment: I don't think there is a straight forward way to do this. You can get the field names using the system field `$Field`, but it does not really link to the data in a meaningful way for what you want to achieve.